# New to python, created a menu with functions I already created

Tags: python, python-3.x, menu

I don't want the menu to be displayed other than at the start or when I enter specific keys. Right now it appearing after every iteration. I'm very new to python

```
myString = input("Please enter a string: ")
a,b,c = countAplha(myString)
choice = ""
for choice in ("a","b","c", "d", "e", "x","m"):
print("A: Count the number of vowels in the string")
print("B: Count the number if consonants in the string")
print("C: Convert the string to uppercase")
print("D: Count the number of numeric character in the string")
print("E: Enter another string")
print("M: Display Menu")

choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
if (choice== "a"):
    print("The number of vowels ares: ",countVowels(myString))
    break
    
elif (choice=="b"):
    print("The number of consonants are: ", countConsonant(myString))
    break
    
elif (choice=="c"):
    print("The string in uppercase is: ",upper(myString))
    break
    
elif (choice=="d"):
    print("The number of numeric characters in the string are: ", b)
    break
    
elif (choice=="e"):
    myString = input("Enter another string")
    choice = ""

    
elif (choice=="m"):
    choice = ""
    
elif (choice=="x"):
    break
```

Comment: Put the whole thing in a [`while`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```py
while True:
    myString = input("Please enter a string: ")
    a,b,c = countAplha(myString)
    choice = ""
    for choice in ("a","b","c", "d", "e", "x","m"):
        print("A: Count the number of vowels in the string")
        print("B: Count the number if consonants in the string")
        print("C: Convert the string to uppercase")
        print("D: Count the number of numeric character in the string")
        print("E: Enter another string")
        print("M: Display Menu")
    
    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if (choice== "a"):
        print("The number of vowels ares: ",countVowels(myString))
        break
        
    elif (choice=="b"):
        print("The number of consonants are: ", countConsonant(myString))
        break
        
    elif (choice=="c"):
        print("The string in uppercase is: ",upper(myString))
        break
        
    elif (choice=="d"):
        print("The number of numeric characters in the string are: ", b)
        break
        
    elif (choice=="e"):
        myString = input("Enter another string")
        choice = ""
    
        
    elif (choice=="m"):
        choice = ""
        
    elif (choice=="x"):
        break
```

This should work, although countAlpha isn't defined when I tested it so I couldn't really double check. Please feel free to comment questions

Comment: Don't you need `i++` inside the while loop?

Comment: Well no because his question seemed liked he wanted it infinite until CTRL + C or whatever.

Comment: In that case, it is more clear to use `while True:`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I don't know why I forgot that existed, will edit it right now